# Solubility of Sodium Chloride

Tags: solubility

I have come to know that, the lattice energy of NaCl is 788 KJ/mol and hydration energy of NaCl is 784 KJ/mol.We know,if lattice energy> hydration energy,the compound won't dissolve.But how is NaCl dissolved in water?

Comment: Dissolving $\ce{NaCl}$ in water is an endothermic process, because of the reasons you mentioned. It simply absorbs some energy from the surroundings; it could be someone physically stirring the solution for example.

Comment: You might want to look at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/317/can-dissolution-reactions-be-endothermic and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94261/how-can-endothermic-reactions-be-spontaneous